# distorted / squished texture on mesh edges

Tags: texturing

I'm having a bit of trouble with textures on my meshes. Here's an example of my issue:

[image: Distorted edges]

The mesh was created by scaling a cube and then applying the scaling via Object > Apply > Scale in object mode. After that, I attempted to apply my material. The texture looks *fine* on the top surface but squished on the edges as shown in the picture.

I'm sure the fix is simple and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default (since you don’t have anything connected to the Vector input of the Voronoi texture node) it will be using Generated coordinates which are dependent on the actual dimensions of your object. The Generated coordinates vary from 0.0 to 1.0 over the extent of the individual X, Y, Z dimensions - but that scale can be different per dimension.

To get a consistent scaling of your texture you need to use texture coordinates which are the same scale in each axis. Add a Texture Coordinate node and connect the Object output of that to the Vector input of your texture and all should be well.

[image: texture coordinate]

Comment: Simple, yet I would have never figured that out on my own. Thank you so much!